# How long would the SQA public beta last?

Tags: discussion

It looks like [SQA site is 2266 days in public beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2241/software-quality-assurance-testing) as of today.

How long would it stay in beta and what should happen to help it get out of beta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site will stay in public beta as long as it needs to. Based on our stats on [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2241/software-quality-assurance-testing) we still need more questions asked per day (preferably good questions) and we still have too many questions that haven't been answered.

We've been one of the slow-growing exchanges that's healthy enough to keep open, but not *quite* ready to go live ever since we passed the 90 day mark, so who knows how much longer we'll need?

Comment: Thanks, gotcha. What do you think we can personally do? Would answering (I mean providing good quality answers) historical unanswered questions help?

Comment: Answering older unanswered questions would help, as would voting to close questions where the OP never registered or hasn't been back in years. Asking good questions also helps.

Comment: Understood. I've been also following selenium and similar test automation specific tags on SO for quite a long time and things around selenium are really quite active on SO, but not here - even though most of these questions asked on SO would be on-topic here as well. If there would be a way to have this traffic go to SQA..

Comment: Unfortunately, many of the Selenium questions here would get downvoted to oblivion on SO because they show so little research effort. Which doesn't help.

Comment: Good point, most of the time it's about an error in an XPath expression or CSS selector, or a screenshot asking to locate a specific element without even a try or even an HTML representation of an element, or about an element which is in an iframe, or about version mismatch between drivers and browsers..and very rarely, ~1 in 10 there is something interesting or at least with a research effort.

Comment: Relevant meta post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/147335

Comment: Do we need to push SO to close testing tickets and point them over to SQA?  Similar to when we point people with Java questions to SO?